# How to enforce rrweb to flush events and fire the emit method

Tags: javascript, rrweb

I am capturing events at the interval of 10 seconds and then saving them to array, later on click of a button I need to grab all the events and send to server. The problem is if I click Send btn before the 10 sec interval then I miss the last few seconds data. Is there any way to force the rrweb to fire emit method with checkout info?

```
let events = [];
let checkedEvents = [];
let stopFn = rrweb.record({
  checkoutEveryNms: 10000,
  emit: (event, isCheckout) => {
    // Push the event to the events array
    events.push(event);
    // If the event is a checkout event, log it to the console
    if (isCheckout) {
      checkedEvents.push(events);
      events = []
    }
  }
});
```

Now lets say if I click the Send button after 16 seconds, then I have data only till 10th second. I need to save the checkedout data so its playable on recorder,otherwise it shows blank page.